# How to send my two models in one view in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
ManageDatabase db = new ManageDatabase();

    //
    // GET: /Addcart/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<UserProfile> Userdetails = db.UserProfiles.Where(m => m.UserName == User.Identity.Name).ToList();

        var _product = from ord in db.Orders
                       where ord.UserId == Userdetails[0].UserId
                       select ord;



        return View(_product);
    }
```

I have two models userprofile and orders.I want to retrieve the orders table where Orders UserId= Logged UserId..But it tells two models is not allowed for 1 view....Pls tell me the solution or tell me the alternate method.

Comment: Unite them under one model class, and pass that into view

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel class:

```
public class UserOrdersVM
{
List<UserProfile> UserDetails {get;set;}
List<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}
```

and in action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  List<UserProfile> Userdetails = db.UserProfiles.Where(m => m.UserName == User.Identity.Name).ToList();

  var _product = (from ord in db.Orders
                  where ord.UserId == Userdetails[0].UserId
                  select ord).ToList();

 UserOrdersVM vm = new UserOrdersVM() { 
                                         UserDetails =Userdetails ,
                                         Orders = _product  
                                        }

 return View(vm);
}
```

and in view:

```
@model UserOrdersVM
```

Comment: Hello Ehsan Sajjad,I pasted your code but it shows this error                                                                                                                                           "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Shopping.Web.Models.UserProfile get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."